# Most efficient SQL, DISTINCT or WHERE...AND

Tags: mysql, sql

Both of these work, but is there a better way to write this?

**1.**

```
SELECT asset_id,
       asset.category_id,
       x,
       y
FROM asset
INNER JOIN map_category
ON map_category.category_id = asset.category_id
WHERE asset.map_id = 5
AND map_category.map_id = 5
```

**2.** (Added `DISTINCT` and removed last line)

```
SELECT DISTINCT asset_id,
       asset.category_id,
       x,
       y
FROM asset
INNER JOIN map_category
ON map_category.category_id = asset.category_id
WHERE asset.map_id = 5
```

Without either `DISTINCT` or the last line `AND map_cate...`, I get 3 records. One for each:

**map_category** table

[image: map_category]

**asset** table

[image: asset]

Comment: EXPLAIN is your friend: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: These queries are not synonymous, if they yield the same result it is coincidental. You have not outlined what you are trying to achieve so it is hard to suggest a more efficient alternative.

Comment: i can't believe no one else sees foreign key consists of 2 columns :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two queries do completely different things. `DISTINCT` selects only unique `asset_id` rows and another query selects only rows where `asset.map_id = 5`.

The reason you have the same result is your data. On some other data you will have completely different results. So you can't compare efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

since your foreign key consists of both the columns, you should join on both columns...

```
SELECT asset_id,
   asset.category_id,
   x,
   y
FROM asset
INNER JOIN map_category
ON map_category.category_id = asset.category_id
AND asset.map_id = map_category.map_id
```

Comment: Awesome, didn't know you could do that!